# Why django geo map not working correctly?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, postgis, qgis

I have already installed django ,postgresql, postgis, Qgis and GDAL

Map show like this.

Nothing to show on the map

How can I fix geoDjango problem ?

[image]

at models.py:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class Shop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    location = models.PointField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

at setting.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [ 
     'django.contrib.gis',   # geo,
     'geoshops',    # user apps
     
          ]
try:
    import gdal
    gdal_path = Path(gdal.__file__)
    OSGEO4W = os.path.join(gdal_path.parent, 'osgeo')
    os.environ["OSGEO4W_ROOT"] = OSGEO4W
    os.environ["GDAL_DATA"] = os.path.join(OSGEO4W, "data", "gdal")
    os.environ["PROJ_LIB"] = os.path.join(OSGEO4W, "data", "proj")
    os.environ["PATH"] = OSGEO4W + ";" + os.environ["PATH"]
    GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = str(os.path.join(OSGEO4W, "geos_c.dll"))
    GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = str(os.path.join(OSGEO4W, "gdal301.dll"))
except ImportError:
    GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = None
    GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = None

if os.name == 'nt':
    import platform
    OSGEO4W = r"C:\OSGeo4W"
    if '64' in platform.architecture()[0]:
        OSGEO4W += "64"
    assert os.path.isdir(OSGEO4W), "Directory does not exist: " + OSGEO4W
    os.environ['OSGEO4W_ROOT'] = OSGEO4W
    os.environ['GDAL_DATA'] = OSGEO4W + r"\share\gdal"
    os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = OSGEO4W + r"\share\proj"
    os.environ['PATH'] = OSGEO4W + r"\bin;" + os.environ['PATH']
```

Comment: It looks like that widget for the `location` field is loaded but actual tiles for the map don't. Could you share how do you register your model in the admin? Also worth checking if there are any JS errors in your browser's console.

Comment: @rootart.



No JS errors.


# register "Shop" model to admin ===> 
        admin.site.register(Shop)

Comment: you can try using `OSMGeoAdmin` class and for your custom `ShopAdmin` and further register the model using it. 
```

class ShopAdmin(OSMGeoAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(Shop, ShopAdmin)
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to install “django-geoposition-2”.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).